# Migrate PHP version - The "" plugin does not exist

Tags: 9, configuration, updating, plugins

I'm using Drupal 9.3.11 on PHP 7.3. Site is running perfectly. I need upgrade to PHP 8, but I am getting this error.

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\ImageToolkit\ImageToolkitManager are: gd in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 53 of core\lib\Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DiscoveryTrait.php).
>
> Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition(NULL) (Line: 102)
> Drupal\Core\Image\ImageFactory->getSupportedExtensions() (Line: 386)
> Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle->supportsUri('public://slider-front/slider_novo_site.jpg') (Line: 274)
> template_preprocess_image_style(Array, 'image_style', Array) (Line: 287)
> Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('image_style', Array) (Line: 422)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 201)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 479)
> Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array, 'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 50)
> __TwigTemplate_ff68c0131a8924feadb3a658b99a0e39b60fe7e6871ff9c20fd45f0a1c6eddd2->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 405)
> Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
> Twig\Template->display(Array) (Line: 390)
> Twig\Template->render(Array) (Line: 55)
> twig_render_template('themes/bootstrap_barrio/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig', Array) (Line: 384)
> Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('image_formatter', Array) (Line: 422)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 201)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 934)
> Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField->render_item(0, Array) (Line: 1168)
> Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase->advancedRender(Object) (Line: 238)
> template_preprocess_views_view_field(Array, 'views_view_field', Array) (Line: 287)
> Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('views_view_field', Array) (Line: 422)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 201)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 1745)
> Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase->theme(Object) (Line: 779)
> Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->elementPreRenderRow(Array)
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 101)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. See [https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725'](https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725%27), 'exception', 'Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface') (Line: 772)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array) (Line: 363)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 201)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 718)
> Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->renderFields(Array) (Line: 584)
> Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->renderGrouping(Array, Array) (Line: 38)
> Drupal\slick_views\Plugin\views\style\SlickViews->render(Array) (Line: 2170)
> Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->render() (Line: 1533)
> Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->render() (Line: 131)
> Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\Block->execute() (Line: 1630)
> Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->executeDisplay('block_1', Array) (Line: 81)
> Drupal\views\Element\View::preRenderViewElement(Array) (Line: 59)
> Drupal\views\Plugin\Block\ViewsBlock->build() (Line: 171)
> Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder::preRender(Array)
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 101)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. See [https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725'](https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725%27), 'exception', 'Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface') (Line: 772)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array) (Line: 363)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 435)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 201)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 479)
> Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array, 'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 65)
> __TwigTemplate_7a1eb4fdd27d5860cb55c9b00c20aed750382ae62ea6694627bee55885014fbc->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 405)
> Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
> Twig\Template->display(Array) (Line: 390)
> Twig\Template->render(Array) (Line: 55)
> twig_render_template('themes/bootstrap_barrio/templates/layout/page.html.twig', Array) (Line: 384)
> Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('page', Array) (Line: 422)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 201)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 479)
> Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array, 'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 84)
> __TwigTemplate_31a2a24787fe3ae65266581f36c28768a486bdf9651fc0c4f5454cf5c1711248->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 405)
> Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
> Twig\Template->display(Array) (Line: 390)
> Twig\Template->render(Array) (Line: 55)
> twig_render_template('themes/bootstrap_barrio/templates/layout/html.html.twig', Array) (Line: 384)
> Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('html', Array) (Line: 422)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 201)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 162)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent{closure}() (Line: 564)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 163)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
> call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 142)
> Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(Object, 'kernel.view') (Line: 163)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 80)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 191)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->fetch(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 128)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->lookup(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 82)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Although version 7.3 works perfectly, the status report contains the following:

[image]

Comment: Did you check the Status Report for any complaints Drupal might have about the new PHP package, specifically the Image Toolkit?

Comment: @4uk4 thanks for your contribuition, but, I'm not found any problem about it.

Comment: You need to install the same PHP extensions for the new version as were available in the old (or at least the ones relevant to Drupal). For GD, for example, that might be `apt install php8.0-gd` on Ubuntu with the ondrej/php PPA. You may also be missing zip, xml, curl, mbstring, and others

Comment: If the GD extension or any required extension isn't installed, the status report complains with a *Drupal requires you to enable the PHP extensions in the following list* error.

Comment: There are two errors: one is about the image toolkit plugin with an empty ID, the other one is about a #pre_render callback with a wrong value.

Comment: Interesting, the second error doesn't seem to stop code execution. It's also not related to the PHP version, this is caused by updating Drupal 8 to 9. So it's not running perfectly with Drupal 9 as the OP says. They should fix this error first and add more info about the PHP 8.0 environment.

Comment: @Clive I'm using XAMPP on windows, after send it to web hosting. The experiences I've had is that usually when installing XAMPP it already contains everything needed to run drupal.

Comment: @Clive The error is not allowing me to access the status report. Looking at the status report in PHP version 7.3, the only error is the one I updated above, in the question.
 Could the webform error be related?

Comment: I'm using a subtheme created in the barrio. I don't know if that could be a problem either. https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php.ini (version 7), gd extension is enable with following code:

```
extension=gd2
```

But, in php.ini of PHP 8 version, command extension=gd2 not working. Correct command is:

```
extension=gd
```

I was trying to use version 7 command in version 8. I remove "2" character and problem solved.